# How to get price of specific sku from an order

Tags: magento-1.8, php, orders

I'm trying to get the price of a specific sku if it exists on an order, here's what my current code is:

```
$itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
        $sku = $item->sku;
        if($sku == 'MySku') {
            $price = $item->getPrice;
        }
    }
```

I believe `$price = $item->getPrice;` is incorrect, I'm just not sure how to grab the line-item price for `MySku` from the order.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few errors in your code. Also we can't know in which file you're trying to execute this code so I couldn't test it.

```
$itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    if($sku == 'MySku') {
        $price = $item->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot -- I'll provide more code if I can't get this snippet to work.